# (Python 3.6) Discord bot refreshing a list based on non-existent names

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, asynchronous, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that allows me to check every single name in a certain list that I have saved in a local .txt file and then seeing whether that name exists in a website's database and removes them from the list if they don't.

The problem: The algorithm itself "works". However it skips certain lines of the file whenever I use the command. If I run the command multiple times it actually "does" its job, however I would prefer if it did it all in 1 go. What I think is wrong is the fact that each loop cycle does not wait for the other one to end so it just fails or something?

```
@client.command()
async def refresh():

    try: ##this part of the code turns my txt file into an array
            with open('snipelist.txt') as f: lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
            endstring = 'Removed from the list: \n'
            ##in this for loop I check if the name in the list exists inside of the website's database
            for line in lines:
                    request = requests.get('http://armory.warmane.com/api/character/'+line+'/Frostwolf/match-history')
                    content = request.content
                    soup = bs(content,'html.parser')
                    string = str(soup)
                    if 'Character does not exist' in string:
                            endstring = endstring + line + '\n'
                            lines.remove(line)
                            f = open('snipelist.txt','w')
                            for line in lines:
                                    f.write('%s\n' % line)
                            f.close()
##this is where I print on the chat itself
            await client.say(endstring)
    except Exception as e:
            print('Error caught during refresh command: ' + str(e))
```

Here are some existing names for the list:
Purple, Smiling, Superman

Here are some nonexisting names:
Neeeew, Teeeest, Eeetcera

Comment: You should be using a non-blocking library like `aiohttp` for your requests.  The `requests` library doesn't play nice with async code. How else is this file being accessed? Is it possible for you to read it just once, when your bot starts, and then only update it when it changes? Also, your problem is likely related to `lines.remove(line)`.  Changing iterables while iterating over them almost always causes problems

Comment: It was as you said, lines.remove(line) in the iteration was what caused the problem. It was such a silly error that completely flew over my head. Thanks a lot for being so fast at replying and being so helpful and concise with alternative solutions as well!